# CGRect init error in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, mkannotationview

The following code returns a couple of compiler errors after converting to swift3:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) { //Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
    super.init(frame: frame) //Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'MKAnnotationView'
}
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Your code miss the context. What exactly are you initialising ?

Comment: Please post the complete code. Post the entire class/Struct/extension where you have this function.

Comment: Look into the documentation what the designated initializer of the target class is.

Comment: @TheAppMentor I am using FBAnnotationCluster cocoa framework. In this framework I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (from the comment in your code) that you are trying to create a subclass of MKAnnotationView. If thats true, try this.

```
class myAnnot : MKAnnotationView{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but the solution is still not working.